# WPF- How can i use a List that i declare and fill in my MainWindow in a Usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, user-controls

Hi i need to be able to use a list from my Main Window in a Usercontrol i need to be able to edit and read from it in various Usercontrols.

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Termin> termine = new List<Termin>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Usercontrol:

```
 public partial class KalenderAnsicht : UserControl
{
    public KalenderAnsicht()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        //i need to be able to use the list here
    }

}
```

Comment: Pass the list to the method as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the `MainWindow` one way or another. The easiest way to do this is probably to use the `Application.Current.Windows` property:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    var mw = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
    List<Termin> termine = mw.termine;
    //...
}
```

You could also consider making `termine` `static`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static List<Termin> termine = new List<Termin>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

...and access it directly without a reference to an instance of `MainWindow`:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    List<Termin> termine = MainWindow.termine;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.I get an error Cannot assign method group to an implicitly typed variable. I can't make it static as i need to be able to edit it from another usercontrol.

Comment: You can still make it static...where do you get the error?

Comment: I get the error here 
var mw = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault;

can i still add new entries to the list from a usercontrol if I make it static?

Comment: sorry keep pressing enter to make a new line and posting on accident :)

Comment: FirstOrDefault is a method. You are missing the parentheses: FirstOrDefault();